# How to remove Session datatable row on click of a Button inside Datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, delete-row, datalist

**How to delete data from session datatable using button inside datalist?**

This code is to display product added inside shopping cart and bremove button is used to remove that item from datalist

*Front End Code*

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" Width="100%" HorizontalAlign="Center">
  <ItemStyle BorderStyle="Double" />
  <ItemTemplate>
    <center>
      <table class="table" style="border-style: dashed; top: 211px; left: 23px; height: auto; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <asp:Image ID="Pimg" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Pimg") %>' CssClass="img img-responsive" Height="140px" Width="240px" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Pname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Pname") %>'></asp:Label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Pqty" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Pqty") %>'></asp:Label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Price" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>'></asp:Label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Button ID="bremove" runat="server" Text="Remove" OnClick="bremove_Click" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </center>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

*Back End Code*

```
 protected void bremove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = DataList1.SelectedIndex;
        DataTable dt = Session["AddToCard"] as DataTable;
        dt.Rows[index].Delete();
        porductlist = dt;
        BindData();
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
 public void BindData()
    {
        DataList1.DataSource = porductlist;
        DataList1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: how can i remove data from session made of datatable on click of button inside Datalist? session data is bind inside Datalist i want to remove single row of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `AcceptChanges()`

```
protected void bremove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = DataList1.SelectedIndex;
    DataTable dt = Session["AddToCard"] as DataTable;

    dt.Rows[index].Delete();
    dt.AcceptChanges();

    DataList1.DataSource = dt;
    DataList1.DataBind();

    porductlist = dt;
    BindData();
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

But you call `BindData()` AND redirect, redirecting is not necessary. Unless you want to go to another page in which case the `BindData()` is not necessary.

**UPDATE**

To get the correct row number, use a button with a `Command`, not a `Click` and send the row number as `CommandArgument`.

```
<asp:Button ID="bremove" runat="server" Text="Button" OnCommand="bremove_Command" CommandArgument='<%# Container.ItemIndex %>' />

protected void bremove_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @vdwwd

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom attribute (e.g. id of your db-entry) to your button:

```
<asp:Button ID="bremove" runat="server" Text="Remove" OnClick="bremove_Click" entry-id='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
```

then in codebehind you can read out the attribute:

```
 protected void bremove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      string id = ((Button)sender).Attributes["data-id"];
      // .. your code .. 
 }
```

Comment: thanks @user1519979 i have tried your step but it deletes the Data present at 0 position row in Datatable

Answer (score 0):

please reassign update dt into session variable to update Session values .

```html
 protected void bremove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = DataList1.SelectedIndex;
        DataTable dt = Session["AddToCard"] as DataTable;
        dt.Rows[index].Delete();
        porductlist = dt;
        Session["AddToCard"]= dt
        BindData();
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
 public void BindData()
    {
        DataList1.DataSource = porductlist;
        DataList1.DataBind();
    }
```